# load local html to vb.net vb10

Tags: html, vb.net

I need help, please..any help would be very helpful..

I want my app in vb.net to load a local HTML file. I have tried using the following code.

```
  Dim appPath As String
    appPath = Application.StartupPath
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("file:///" & IO.Path.GetFullPath(".\trial1.html"))
```

but it says "An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: Navigation to a relative URL unsuccessful."

where did I go wrong? , what are the things I should do?and where must I place my html file? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application.StartupPath returns the path for the executable file that started the application.

Using IO.Path.GetFullPath should work if you place the HTML file in ether your ..\bin\Debug folder (or if you have VS set to compile your code to Release, place the HTML file in your ..\bin\Release) under your project folder,

and if you deploy the *.exe you have to put the HTML in the same folder as the *.exe

Comment: Thank you for replying, so my code above will work if ill olace my html file to debug folder?

Comment: Yep, should do... And if you change the code to.. WebBrowser1.Navigate(appPath & ".\default.html")                                  that should also work...